# How do you write an if/then stmt in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I understand from Papa Crockford that it's a good idea to use semicolons.  And I understand that it's a good idea to use curly braces even to block just one line of JavaScript in the body of an if/then stmt.

So my question is: Where do I place the semicolon?  Do I do this:

```
if (condition) {
   stmt;
} else {
   stmt;
}
```

or do I do this:

```
if (condition) {
   stmt
} else {
   stmt
};
```

or do I leave the semicolon off altogether?
(Given that I have decided to use curly braces to block even just 1 line of JavaScript inside the body of an if/then).

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the consent is to use the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer is 1st option.**

you must read about it for better understanding. this is the very basic thing of javascript.

## [Reference - 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_ifelse.htm)

## [Reference - 2](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptelseif.php)

Comment: Thank you for those two references dku.rajkumar!

Answer (score 3):

You do the first.  Semicolons do not go after the closing braces of if and else statements.

The only time I can think of when you would *ever* put a semicolon after a closing brace is if you were assigning a function to some sort of property, or creating an object literal:

```
var obj = { };
obj.func = function() {
    alert("Howdy!");
};
```

Comment: But I just don't like seeing a semicolon followed by a curly brace.  To me, the curly brace is a line terminator as well.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the proper form, because you can have multiple statements and they should be separated by semicolons.

Comment: Ah yes, if that were true, then the other would be true.  But what if I only have 1 statement?